# Animation issues with IOS 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uiviewanimation

I'm simply trying to move two views upwards in the simplest manner, and I can't figure out how to make it work on iOS8 (but its works just fine on iOS7).

I've read that changes happened but I can't make it work anyway...

Here is the code i'm using :

CGRect txFrame;  //the initial frame of my textview
CGRect btFrame;  //the initial frame of my button

```
- (void)kbWillShow{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.45 animations:^{
            //Remembering the initial frames here
            txFrame = _txReason.frame;
            btFrame = _btSend.frame;
            _lbTitleReason.alpha = 0.3;
            //Animating
            _txReason.frame = CGRectMake(txFrame.origin.x, txFrame.origin.y-55, txFrame.size.width, txFrame.size.height);
            _btSend.frame = CGRectMake(btFrame.origin.x, btFrame.origin.y-75, btFrame.size.width, btFrame.size.height);

        }completion:nil];

    }

    - (void)kbWillHide{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.45 animations:^{
            //Putting them back to their original positions.
            _txReason.frame = txFrame;
            _btSend.frame = btFrame;
            _lbTitleReason.alpha = 1;
        }completion:nil];

    }
```

I've tried putting the "result" position in the completion block but I just does a very abrupt and weird movement, and after the duraton the view teleports to the intented position. (Which is better than doing an abrupt movement and ending up at the exact same position as it started).

This should be simple, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should play with the `center` property instead of the `frame` in your case.

Comment: i think i had already try but maybe not properly, could you give me a example ?

Comment: example...? you should do the exact same thing, but with the `center` property rather than the `frame`. I'm not sure which example you'd really like to see. it takes more time to write this comment than changing your actual code for using the `center` property instead. :)

Comment: I don't see how using center property would do any difference to solve this problem. When are these animations called, and do you have AutoLayout enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this and the answer is to do with the layout constraints. You need to change the constant properties of the layout constraints that affect the view you want to change.

E.g. to change the width of a view with a width `NSLayoutConstraint` you would call `constraint.constant = newWidth;` then go ahead with your animation code. This is how I'm doing it and it works fine.

EDIT: your animation code is fine. You don't need to play with the `centre` property.